# Can CHttpFile or HttpSendRequest use windows credential manager?

Tags: winapi, mfc, wininet

I use `CHttpFile` from MFC to execute http requests. When authentication is needed, I use `ErrorDlg` (`InternetErrorDlg`) to pop up a user/password dialog. That dialog has a checkbox to save the credentials. But that works only while my process is running. After restarting the process, the credentials must be entered again.

I would like to use credentials from Windows Credential manager to automatically pick credentials for configured servers.

Can `CHttpFile` or the WinInet-API use credentials from the Windows Credential manager?

This demonstrates how I use the API currently:

```
CInternetSession session(_T("myapp"), 1);
DWORD dwOpenFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;
CHttpConnection *pServer = session.GetHttpConnection(_T("some server"), dwOpenFlags, 443);
if(NULL != pServer)
{
  CHttpFile *pFile = pServer->OpenRequest(CHttpConnection::HTTP_VERB_GET, _T("some URL"), NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, dwOpenFlags);
  if(pFile != NULL)
  {
    if(!pFile->AddRequestHeaders(_T("some headers")))
    {
      // error handling...      
    }
    if(!pFile->SendRequest())
    {
      // error handling...
    }

    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    pFile->QueryInfoStatusCode(dwStatus);
    if(dwStatus == HTTP_STATUS_DENIED)
    {
      // can I do something here or before the SendRequest call
      // to use credentials from the Windows Credential manager?
      dwStatus = pFile->ErrorDlg(NULL, ERROR_INTERNET_INCORRECT_PASSWORD,
                                 FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS |
                                 FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS |
                                 FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA);
    }
  }
}
```